# is there any way to calculate % match between 2 strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

Is there any way to calculate % match between 2 strings?

i have a situation where it is required to calculate matches between 2 strings if there is 85%

match then i will combine 2 tables, i have written the code for combining 2 tables

my sample strings are :

```
var str1 = 'i love javascript';
var str2 = 'i love javascripttt';

var matchPer = match(str1,str2); // result might be 80% , 85%, 90% ,95% etc
```

Comment: What's your logic for calculating the percentage?

Comment: There's not just *a* way, there are *lots* of ways. Do you have any guideline for choosing one? What does "85% match" actually mean to you?

Comment: `1 - levenshtein(str1, str2) / max(str1.length, str2.length)` seems like a reasonable metric to me, but you might want Damerau-Levenshtein (which considers the difference between "bacon" and "baocn" to be 1 instead of 2), or Hamming distance as in Ala Eddine JEBALI's answer, which is unforgiving of additions and deletions ("bananas" and "ananas" have a Levenshtein distance of 1 but a Hamming distance of 6. Are they 14% similar or 86% similar?)

Comment: @hobbs Please post that as an answer

Comment: More relevant info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/joshaven/string_score

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

```js
var str1 = 'i love javascript';
var str2 = 'i love javascripttt';

function match(str1, str2){
    var tmpValue = 0;
    var minLength = str1.length;
 if(str1.length > str2.length){
  var minLength = str2.length;
 } 
    var maxLength = str1.length;
 if(str1.length < str2.length){
  var maxLength = str2.length;
 }
    for(var i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        if(str1[i] == str2[i]) {
            tmpValue++;
        }
    }
    var weight = tmpValue / maxLength;
    return (weight * 100) + "%";
}

var matchPer = match(str1,str2);
console.log(matchPer); //outputs: 89.47%
console.log( match("aaaaa", "aaaaa") ); //outputs: 100%
console.log( match("aaaaa", "aXaaa") ); //outputs: 80%
console.log( match("aaaaa", "aXXaa") ); //outputs: 60%
console.log( match("aaaaa", "aXXXa") ); //outputs: 40%
console.log( match("aaaaa", "aXXXX") ); //outputs: 20%
```

Comment: Please exoplain what this is; don't juist dump code.